# asp.net mvc model item passed in to dictionary is of type List

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc view which is strongly typed  view  and i have a controller which returns
the ilist user based on the id provided. I am getting the following above error:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.User]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Data.User'.**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Data.User>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{%> <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>            
<fieldset> 

 <legend>Fields</legend>                
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id) %>
                </div>                
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName) %>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>     

     public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
            {

                    var usr = _UsrService.GerUserById(id).ToList<User>();                
                    return View(usr);
            }
```

Comment: I edited your post to separate the Controller from the View.  If you delete the text between the two code blocks (I just wrote "Controller") it looks like one single code block (which looks strange)

Comment: also, is this a typo? `GerUserById` shouldn't it be `GetUserById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a List to a modal that is to display a single item.

Try removing the `.ToList<User>` so that it looks something like

```
Data.User usr = _UsrService.GetUserById(id).FirstOrDefault;
return View(usr)
```

Comment: also, i changed the example to say `GetUserById` instead of `GerUserById` since it looked like you had a typo in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

You've strongly typed your view class to a single instance of `Data.User`.  Your action method is attempting to create the view by handing it a `List<User>`.

Since it looks like you just want to display a single user, try changing your action method to just get one user, like this:

```
 public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
 {

    var usr = _UsrService.GerUserById(id).FirstOrDefault();                
    return View(usr);
 }
```

I'm assuming that the `GerUserById(id)` method is returning an `IEnumerable` of some kind, since you're calling the `ToList<>` method on it.  This means that even if it is a list of one item, you still need to get the object out of it, so calling `FirstOrDefault()` will give you the first result in the `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only one user in your system with a given ID (which is sort of the definition of an ID), `_UsrService.GerUserById(id)` should be changed to return a `User` rather than a `List<User>`. Then your controller can just say:

```
return View(_UsrService.GetUserById(id));
```